# Edge IE mode - passing session between Edge and IE-mode

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a two site, say site [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) and [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com).

the way how it works is.

I login into first site using my login username and password. After successful login, the site will open a list of links. On one of the links is the [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com) (legacy app). Clicking on this will open the second site in a new tab.

With the IE browser coming to an End soon. we are forced to use Edge and IE mode.

I have set [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) to open in Edge mode and [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com) in Edge-IE mode.
I have followed the instructions give in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-sitelist
and tried
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare#how-cookie-sharing-works

It seems there is session is not shared between two mode.

below is my xml settings.

not sure if there is something I am missing here.

```
<site-list version="1">
<shared-cookie domain=".site1.com" name="cookie1"></shared-cookie> 
<shared-cookie host=".site1.com" name="cookie2"></shared-cookie>
<site url="site1.com">
<open-in>None</open-in>
</site>
<site url="site2.com">
<open-in>IE11</open-in>
</site>
</site-list>
```

I also found out that it works when site1 and site2 are using both Edge mode or both as IE  mode or both as IE11. But does not work using Edge mode and then IE mode.

I believe I missed something.

Comment: did you ever resolve this ?